# Use IFS in a SPARKLINE CHART

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm at beginner level and trying to modify a template using a SPARKLINE chart. Now I would like the chart color to change depending on the cell value. I have done some research and thought `IFS(CELL>=VALUE,"color#";"color#")` should be correct but I just get an ARRAY_LITTERAL error... Can someone spot where the issue is?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
...; "color", IF (E11=1,"#3Eb489","#000000")})
```